# How can I get my computer to play 4k content smoothly?

Tags: intel-graphics, intel, gpu-driver

The hardware ought to be capable. This problem may broach hardware, configuration and multimedia, but I feel it fits best here, if not I am sorry. My machine is a Gigabyte BRIX S (GB-BKi3HA-7100) with the F4 version of bios installed. Ubuntu is installed to an SSD (fresh install 17.04).

I downloaded some test videos and video playback on 1080 is slightly choppy, and 4k barely plays at all. I understand the Kaby-lake processor in this machine should have no problems playing even 10-bit HEVC video, but I'm lucky if it plays 1fps. A different NUC with nearly identical specs has no problem.

I've tried hooking the computer to my monitor and my TV and the results are the same. The drivers dialog says that the proprietary drivers are in use. I can use the display normally and there's no artifacts or choppiness when moving windows around or when I run glxgears. Youtube seems to play okay except for the tearing/choppiness that I notice.

I've tried mpv media player, VLC, Gnome Mplayer,... they all yield similar results. Note, I also have the problem in firefox

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.3
Release Date: 2017-03-15
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-70-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux mediaman 4.10.0-20-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:22:42 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 28 March 2017 06:16:52AM

Desktop: Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 17.04
Machine: Device: laptop Mobo: GIGABYTE model: MFLP3AP-00 v: 1.x
UEFI: American Megatrends v: F4 date: 02/20/2017
CPU: Dual core Intel Core i3-7100U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
clock speeds: max: 2400 MHz 1: 1424 MHz 2: 790 MHz 3: 731 MHz
4: 763 MHz
Graphics: Card: Intel Device 5916
Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 driver: intel
Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.3
Audio: Card Intel Device 9d71 driver: snd_hda_intel
Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-20-generic
Network: Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection I219-LM driver: e1000e
IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: 1c:1b:0d:8f:9e:11
Card-2: Intel Device 24fb driver: iwlwifi
IF: wlp2s0 state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: 30:e3:7a:92:8a:10
Drives: HDD Total Size: 120.0GB (13.1% used)
ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 120.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 102G used: 7.2G (8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0
ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.46GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-1
RAID: No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors: System Temperatures: cpu: 46.5C mobo: 29.8C
Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info: Processes: 213 Uptime: 11 min Memory: 1152.1/7858.3MB
Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.8
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 02
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:132 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
Release Date: 02/20/2017
Serial services are supported (int 14h)
Manufacturer: GIGABYTE
Product Name: GB-BKi3(H)A-7100
Serial Number: Default string
Manufacturer: GIGABYTE
Product Name: MFLP3AP-00
Serial Number: Default string
Manufacturer: Default string
Serial Number: Default string
Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible
Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Manufacturer: Kingston
Serial Number: C10400A9
Manufacturer: Kingston
Serial Number: BE0400AB
Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Debug Use USB(Disabled:Serial)
cat: /etc/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.3

Not software rendered: yes
Not blacklisted: yes
GLX fbconfig: yes
GLX texture from pixmap: yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program: yes
GL fragment program: yes
GL vertex buffer object: yes
GL framebuffer object: yes
GL version is 1.4+: yes

Unity 3D supported: yes


Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
Module Size Used by
ccm 20480 1
rfcomm 77824 2
cmac 16384 1
bnep 20480 2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi 49152 1
snd_hda_codec_realtek 90112 1
binfmt_misc 20480 1
snd_hda_codec_generic 73728 1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
nls_iso8859_1 16384 1
snd_soc_skl 65536 0
snd_soc_skl_ipc 49152 1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc 16384 1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp 28672 1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_hda_ext_core 24576 1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_match 16384 1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core 233472 1 snd_soc_skl
snd_compress 20480 1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus 16384 1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine 16384 1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel 36864 3
intel_rapl 20480 0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal 16384 0
intel_powerclamp 16384 0
coretemp 16384 0
snd_hda_codec 126976 4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_gen eric,snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm_intel 200704 0
snd_hda_core 81920 7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_s oc_skl,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,sn d_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep 16384 1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm 102400 8 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_ hda_ext_core,snd_hda_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_code c_hdmi,snd_soc_core
kvm 593920 1 kvm_intel
arc4 16384 2
snd_seq_midi 16384 0
snd_seq_midi_event 16384 1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi 32768 1 snd_seq_midi
irqbypass 16384 1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul 16384 0
crc32_pclmul 16384 0
iwlmvm 368640 0
ghash_clmulni_intel 16384 0
mac80211 782336 1 iwlmvm
snd_seq 65536 2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
pcbc 16384 0
snd_seq_device 16384 3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer 32768 2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
iwlwifi 229376 1 iwlmvm
aesni_intel 167936 4
snd 77824 19 snd_compress,snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_h da_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi, snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec _realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
input_leds 16384 0
joydev 20480 0
aes_x86_64 20480 1 aesni_intel
cfg80211 602112 3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
crypto_simd 16384 1 aesni_intel
glue_helper 16384 1 aesni_intel
cryptd 24576 3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
btusb 45056 0
btrtl 16384 1 btusb
mei_me 40960 0
soundcore 16384 1 snd
shpchp 36864 0
mei 102400 1 mei_me
intel_pch_thermal 16384 0
hci_uart 98304 0
btbcm 16384 2 hci_uart,btusb
btqca 16384 1 hci_uart
btintel 16384 2 hci_uart,btusb
bluetooth 557056 33 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btu sb
intel_lpss_acpi 16384 0
intel_lpss 16384 1 intel_lpss_acpi
acp
```

Comment: Which video player did you use? Did you choose a hardware accelerated output ? like vaapi?

Comment: I've tried mpv media player, VLC, Gnome Mplayer,... they all yield similar results. Note, I also have the problem in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the open source Mesa drivers, which according to the [Mesa GL Extensions/Limits Chart](https://people.freedesktop.org/~imirkin/glxinfo/) doesn't officially support Kabylake yet, so this is likely your current issue. You can either wait for support to develop further in Linux or use Windows.

Comment: Are there not proprietary drivers that are available? I chose to allow proprietary drivers during Ubuntu installation. I'm surprised I'm not getting prompted to install them from the additional drivers screen.

Comment: @eeeeeen: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. I found out they're wrong though.